# Как выразить значение из list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
[<User {"id": 1111111111, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "user"}>]
```

как выразить значение id

Comment: нет, вот эта частица кода выводит в чат  await message.answer(message.new_chat_members)

Comment: из документации aiogram мы можем понять 
new_chat_members: Optional[List[User]]
что значение дается в list

Comment: тип данных проверьте `print(type(переменная__которая_содержитЭто))`

Comment: <class 'list'> выдало

Comment: Ну, просто вытащите первый элемент из списка с помощью `[0]` наверное? А дальше уже в документации к классу User смотрите, как из него вытащить id (но возможно `[0].id` прокатит)

Comment: сработало) Сделай это как ответ, я приму его, тебе баллы дадут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конкретно данном примере, Вам следует просто обратиться к списку по нулевому индексy: `some_result = some_list[0]`. Если это из фреймворка aiogram, то, если я не ошибаюсь, достаточно будет написать `some_result.id`.